# Como saber si una cadena de texto hay números en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**Como puedo saber si un `input` de tipo texto hay números**

*tengo el siguiente código*

*Bueno aquí tengo una porción de código para poder entender lo que quiero realizar*

```js
$('#enviar').on("click", function() {
  alert("Estoy dentro");
  if ( typeof $("#nombre").val().trim() === 'string') {
      alert("No se permite numeros");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="Pepe123">
<input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="enviar">
```

*Al momento de enviar valide que si en la cadena de `input` existe algún numero*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede usar una expresión regular sencilla como `\d` para revisar si la cadena contiene al menos un número.

La implementación sería así:

```
// si la cadena contiene al menos un número el método test() devolverá true
if ( /\d/.test($("#nombre").val().trim()) ) {
      alert("No se permite numeros");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolver tu problema utilizando expresiones regulares, aquí te dejo un ejemplo para contar la cantidad de números que tiene un string.

```js
$('#enviar').on("click", function() {
  var input = $("#nombre").val();
  var contar_numeros = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length;
  
  if(contar_numeros == 0){
    alert("no hay números");
  }else{
    alert(contar_numeros);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="Pepe123">
<input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="enviar">
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos